# Create multidimensional array from string in PHP

Tags: php

I would like to convert and array to json in php, I tried firstly to split keys with the '_' separator, but after this I don't know ...

From this input:

```json
[
    "elements_0_image": "",
    "elements_0_content_subtitle": "Subtitle",
    "elements_0_content_title": "Title",
    "elements_0_content_description": "Description",
    "elements_0_content_accordion_0_label": "label",
    "elements_0_content_accordion_0_contenu": "content",
    "elements_0_content_accordion": 1,
    "elements_0_content_button": {
        "title": "",
        "url": "http://test",
        "target": ""
    }
]
```

To this output:

```json
{
    "elements": [
        {
            "image": "",
            "content": {
                "subtitle": "Subtitle",
                "title": "Title",
                "description": "Description",
                "accordion": [
                    {
                        "label": "label",
                        "contenu": "content"
                    }
                ],
                "button": {
                    "title": "",
                    "url": "http://test",
                    "target": "",
                }
            }
        }
    ],
}
```

EDIT:

So based from an old question [Create variable length array from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9145902/create-variable-length-array-from-string)

I tried this:

```php
$output = [];
    foreach ( $reversed as $key => $value ) {
        $keys = explode( '_', $key );
        $last = count( $keys ) - 1;
        $step = &$output;
        foreach ( $keys as $k => $ke ) {
            if ( $k == $last ) {
                $step[ $ke ] = $value;
            } else if ( is_array( $step ) ) {
                $step[ $ke ] = [];
            }
            $step = &$step[ $ke ];
        }
    }
```

but I get

```json
{
            "elements": [
                {
                    "content": {
                        "button": {
                            "title": "",
                            "url": "http://test",
                            "target": "",
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: That's not a PHP array. PHP uses `=>` between keys and values, not `:`.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the sample method to create multidimensional array in php

```
<?php
        // Define a multidimensional array
        $contacts = array(
            array(
                "name" => "Peter Parker",
                "email" => "peterparker@mail.com",
            ),
            array(
                "name" => "Clark Kent",
                "email" => "clarkkent@mail.com",
            ),
            array(
                "name" => "Harry Potter",
                "email" => "harrypotter@mail.com",
            )
        );
        // Access nested value
        echo "Peter Parker's Email-id is: " . $contacts[0]["email"];
        ?>
```

you  can get complete guide from the link as well .

https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/php-tutorial/php-arrays.php

Comment: How does this create the array from the input that they show?